# Python error "Parameters to generic types must be types. Got <module "

Tags: python, python-typing

When trying to use my own class as a type hint :

```
from mycode.ltm import MyClass

def DoSomething(self, values: List[MyClass]) -> None:
```

I get:

> Parameters to generic types must be types. Got <module '...' from
> '...'>.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If you name your class the same as the file name, make sure you import the class, not just the module the file represents. So for example if your MyClass class is defined in MyClass.py the above would need to change to

```
from mycode.ltm.MyClass import MyClass
```